# Deploy ASP.NET MVC core 3 app on Linux Cloud (CentOS 8) with Remote node Docker

Tags: linux, azure, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, centos8

Can anyone guide on Deploy an ASP.NET MVC core 3 app on linux centos8 from azure.

With remote docker node or by the reverse proxy.